# If/Else statement within ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a conditional statement within my `ng-click` function. I have the `if` working, but now I need to figure out how to get an `else`. I have the following code currently:

```
<div ng-click="item.subCategory.length > 1 && showSubCategories();">
```

This runs a function to display my sub-categories if there is more than 1 sub-category within a category. What I would like to do is expand on it so that I can run a different function if there is only 1 sub-category.

In Javascript the statement would look like this:

```
if (item.subCategory.length > 1) {
    showSubCategories();
} else {
    showProducts();
}
```

Is it possible to do that within an `ng-click`?

Comment: Did you try writing that whole if/else block into the `ngClick`?  I would have assumed it would interpolate that correctly.

Comment: or just incorporate the check in the function itself

Comment: @zero298 I was hoping there would be a shorthand way of doing it

Comment: @aw04 I think that would be out of scope as `item` refers to an `ng-repeat` I have on the container of this element.

Comment: Have you tried a ternary operator in there?

Comment: pass the item in

Comment: @Branco I had not, but that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to do this would be to create a wrapper function (obviously name it whatever makes sense to you). This keeps the logic in one place and also scales well (what happens when you need more checks?)

```
showSubCategoriesOrProducts(item) {
  if (item.subCategory.length > 1) {
    showSubCategories();
  } else {
    showProducts();
  }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<div ng-click="showSubCategoriesOrProducts(item)">
```

Comment: I'd suggest using this approach.  Try to avoid muddying your view.  Keep as much logic as you can in your controller.

Comment: Hah he edited from his original to be my answer (see below) @zero298

Comment: @WilliamHampshire huh? my original answer is same solution, edits only to add words/details

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Ternary operators are available to ng-click:

```
<div ng-click="item.subCategory.length > 1 ? showSubCategories() : showProducts()">
```

That should let you do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="onClick(item);">
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.onClick = function(item) {
  if (item.subCategory.length > 1) {
    showSubCategories();
  }
  else {
    showProducts();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work

```
ng-click="item.subCategory.length > 1? showSubCategories() : showProducts()" .
```

here, the part before **"?"** is the condition. If it is true, the part after **"?"** i.e. **showSubCategories()** will execute. If the condition is false the later will be executed